# preg_match(): No ending delimiter

Tags: preg-match, delimiter

We are using ViPER Guestbook in our websites and getting following error messages:

```
[20-Jun-2015 12:01:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found in /home/...../...../gb/index.php on line 277
[20-Jun-2015 12:01:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found in /home/....../...../gb/index.php on line 278
```

These lines are:

```
(!preg_match("/^".PFIX."CUSTOM",$_key)) &&
(!preg_match("/^".PFIX."RATING",$_key))) {
```

The full code is:

```
      $_b = true;
  foreach ($arg as $_key => $_val) {
    if ((!in_array($_key,$_paramlist)) &&
        (!preg_match("/^".PFIX."CUSTOM",$_key)) &&
        (!preg_match("/^".PFIX."RATING",$_key))) {
      if (is_array($_val)) {
        foreach ($_val as $_inkey => $_inval) {
          $_param .= "&amp;".urlencode($_key)."[".
          urlencode($_inkey)."]=".urlencode($_inval);
        }
      }
      else {
        $_param .= "&amp;".urlencode($_key)."=".urlencode($_val);
      }
    }
    elseif ($_key != PFIX."decode")
      $_b = false;
  }
```

Where should the ending delimiter '/' be in this code?

Please help.

Thanks.

Lakshmanan

Comment: Assuming you are not trying to match a literal `/` at the start, it goes at the end of the expression: `"/^".PFIX."RATING/"`  Your regex delimiters are `/` based on the pattern's first character, so you need to end the pattern with the same character.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

We have corrected the code to as follows:

```
    (!preg_match("/^".PFIX."CUSTOM/",$_key)) &&
    (!preg_match("/^".PFIX."RATING/",$_key))) {
```

and there is no error messages as of now.

Thanks,

Lakshmanan